# While accessing JNI interface why does C requires an extra level of indirection while C++ doesn't?

Tags: java, c++, c, java-native-interface

In the code [sample](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#wp186) for accessing via "C", the env pointer is used like:

```
const char *str = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, s, 0);
```

While for C++, the [sample](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#wp224) makes the same call:

```
const char *str = env->GetStringUTFChars(s, 0);
```

The document goes on to say:

> With C++, the extra level of indirection and the interface pointer argument disappear from the source code. However, the underlying mechanism is exactly the same as with C. In C++, JNI functions are defined as inline member functions that expand to their C counterparts.

Does that statement mean that the C++ version would eventually expand to the C version and have the same level of indirection?

I haven't looked at the header files, but I'm puzzled. Can someone explain this difference?

Comment: @KerrekSB: Relax, buddy. It's hyperlinked.

Comment: [Did you look at the links I pointed to the sample code?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html)

Comment: @KerrekSB And a standard part of JNI...

Comment: I agree with @KerrekSB. You pasted the above code, couldn't you just paste a few more lines so that we get the full picture without having to Ctrl-F anything, or search google for typedefs or API documentation?

Comment: @netcoder: You can't click a link that either? It's hyperlinked right there in the question. Man, what a bunch of nitpickers.

Comment: At the cost of Rat-holing into this discussion, I pasted the links to specifically the parts of the documentation. So, if you would've simply clicked the links, it would've directly put you right in front of the source code. It's not just linked to the page but also the appropriate section where the code is present. I don't really understand what you're complaining about...

Comment: I find the question intriguing, though @KerrekSB (direct as always) brings a pretty good point. The time it took to *write* the question could have been spent rectifying the "I haven't looked at the header files" making the question moot to begin with. Still, good answers, so thats a plus.

Answer (score 4):

The explanation quoted in the question explains it. C++ supports such things as inline member functions, but C does not. The C++ definition of `JNIEnv` includes function definitions that the C definition doesn't. The C++ definition would look like this:

```
char const* JNIEnv::GetStringUTFChars(jstring s, jint i)
{
  return (*this)->GetStringUTFChars(this, s, i);
}
```

The function called in the C version is really a function pointer. Essentially, a `JNIEnv*` is a vptr, pointing to a struct with a bunch of JNI-supplied function pointers. C++ provides additional definitions directly in `JNIEnv` as a convenience, to avoid having to repeat the `this` parameter of the function call.

Comment: +1 This is fundamentally *identical* to the mechanics for executing a COM method from C++ vs. C, for anyone that has not had the privilege (read curse) of dealing with C-based COM code. In C, you're handed a "vtbl" pointer that you must dereference to get to the actual function pointer to call; in C++, you get a *this* pointer, which nicely does half that work for you.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't checked exactly how they've implemented it but I am pretty confident it is like this:

- In C++ the JNIEnv* will be "this" for the method which makes it possible for the methods to use the env pointer as well
- In C, the only way for the function (which the function pointer in the struct is pointing to) can use it, is if someone passes it as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

So, looking at the [OpenJDK source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7-gate/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/javavm/export/jni.h), the jni.h has this in the header:

```
770 /*
771  * We use inlined functions for C++ so that programmers can write:
772  *
773  *    env->FindClass("java/lang/String")
774  *
775  * in C++ rather than:
776  *
777  *    (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/String")
778  *
779  * in C.
780  */
781 
782 struct JNIEnv_ {
783     const struct JNINativeInterface_ *functions;
784 #ifdef __cplusplus
785 
786     jint GetVersion() {
787         return functions->GetVersion(this);
788     }
```

Thanks everyone for clarifying this.